# Perl script is producing the symbol Â while converting an Excel file to CSV

Tags: perl

We have a batch process in our system which will convert an Excel .xlsx file to CSV format using Perl. When it converts the CSV file it produces some symbols like Â, so I am not getting the expected result. Can some please help me how to use the same value as in the Excel file while converting to CSV?

#### Value in Excel file:

```
Unverifiable License Documentation  NB Only
```

#### Value converted in CSV through Perl:

```
Unverifiable License Documentation Â– NB Only
```

I want to retain the same value that is in Excel while converting to CSV

**Note:** I used Encoding(UTF-8) while opening the file but even then it didn't work.

#### My Perl code

```
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
use File::Basename;
use set_env_cfg;
use Date::Simple (':all');
use Math::Round;

$sts = open( INP, "< ${if}" );
#$sts = open (INP, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', ${if}       );
#$sts = open (INP, '<:encoding(ISO-8859-1)', ${if}       );

if ( $sts == 0 ) {

    print LOG tmstmp() . ": Error opening input file\n";
    close LOG;
    print LOG "$ldlm\n";
    `cp $lf $od`;
    die;
}

print LOG "$ldlm\n";
print LOG tmstmp() . ": Conversion started for $if\n";

$oBook = Spreadsheet::XLSX->new($if);

foreach $WkS ( @{ $oBook->{Worksheet} } ) {

    print LOG tmstmp() . ": Converting worksheet                            -----  " . $WkS->{Name}, "\n";

    $cfgrec = '';    # initialize the configure record

    $sts = open( OUT, ">$od/$WkS->{Name}.txt" );

    if ( $sts == 0 ) {

        print LOG tmstmp() . ": Error opening output file\n";
        close LOG;
        close INP;
        print LOG "$ldlm\n";

        `cp $lf $od`;
        die;
    }

    $WkS->{MaxRow} ||= $WkS->{MinRow};

    foreach $iR ( $WkS->{MinRow} .. $WkS->{MaxRow} ) {

        $WkS->{MaxCol} ||= $WkS->{MinCol};

        print OUT $cfgkey if ( ( $cfgko == 0 ) && ( $iR >= $hdrcnt ) );

        foreach $iC ( $WkS->{MinCol} .. $WkS->{MaxCol} ) {

            $cell = $WkS->{Cells}[$iR][$iC];

            if ($cell) {

                if ( ( $cell->{Type} ) eq "Date" ) {

                    if ( int( $cell->{Val} ) == ( $cell->{Val} ) ) {
                        $tmpval = date("1900-01-01") + ( $cell->{Val} ) - 2;
                    }
                    else {

                        $css = round( ( ( $cell->{Val} ) - int( $cell->{Val} ) ) * 86400 );
                        $cmi = int( $css / 60 );
                        $chr = int( $css / 3600 );

                        $css = $css - $cmi * 60;
                        $cmi = $cmi - $chr * 60;

                        $tmpval = date("1900-01-01") + int( $cell->{Val} ) - 2;
                        $tmpval .= " $chr:$cmi:$css";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $tmpval = Spreadsheet::XLSX::Utility2007::unescape_HTML( $cell->{Val} );
                }

                print OUT $tmpval;    ###Added double quotes in txt file to handle the comma delimiter value
            }

            if ( ( $iR == ${hdr_seq} - 1 ) ) {

                if ( ( $cell->{Type} ) eq "Date" ) {

                    if ( int( $cell->{Val} ) == ( $cell->{Val} ) ) {

                        $tmpval = date("1900-01-01") + ( $cell->{Val} ) - 2;
                    }
                    else {

                        $css = round( ( ( $cell->{Val} ) - int( $cell->{Val} ) ) * 86400 );
                        $cmi = int( $css / 60 );
                        $chr = int( $css / 3600 );

                        $css = $css - $cmi * 60;
                        $cmi = $cmi - $chr * 60;

                        $tmpval = date("1900-01-01") + int( $cell->{Val} ) - 2;
                        $tmpval .= " $chr:$cmi:$css";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $tmpval = Spreadsheet::XLSX::Utility2007::unescape_HTML( $cell->{Val} );
                }

                $cfgrec .= $tmpval;
            }

            if ( ( $iC == 0 ) && ( $iR == ${hdr_seq} ) ) {

                $cfgrec = uc($cfgrec);
                $cfgko  = cnt_ocr( $cfgrec, $keyhdr );
                $cfgkey = "*|" x ( $klm - $cfgko );
            }

            print OUT "|" if ( $iC < $WkS->{MaxCol} );

            print OUT $cfgkey if ( ( $cfgko == $iC + 1 ) && ( $iR >= $hdrcnt ) );
        }

        print OUT "\n";

    }

    print LOG tmstmp() . ": Worsheet conversion completed successfully      -----  " . $WkS->{Name}, "\n";

    close OUT;

    push @csv_file_lst, "$WkS->{Name}.txt";

}

print LOG tmstmp() . ": Conversion completed successfully for $if\n";
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
use File::Basename;
use set_env_cfg;
use Date::Simple (':all');
use Math::Round;

Comment: A hex editor or hex dump of the .csv file, with ascii, is likely to be your friend.... look at the actual byte values.  A clash between encoding formats (UTF-8 vs straight ASCII vs other encoding formats) would be high on my suspect list.

Comment: You must show your Perl code if you want to get a sensible answer to this

Comment: Added the code, Please help on this.

Comment: Hi Borodin, I Have added the code, can you please review and let me what needs to be added to retain the same value in CSV as in Excel.

Comment: Have you considered formatting your code in a readable manner? You're asking us to help you. It's usually a good idea to make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: @DaveCross: It's essential that character data is represented as accurately as possible, especially in questions like this. While blockquotes may look cute, they also replace multiple whitespace with a single space character, and autowrap the result. That's usually inapproriate for data of any sort

Comment: It's vital to *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare every variable with `my` as late as possible. You should also keep your code tidy so that both yourself and others can follow it easily. I've reformatted your code for you in this case, and I hope you will agree that there's a substantial improvement to clarity

Comment: @Borodin: Good point. Apologies :-/

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that your Excel file contains data encoded using the Windows-1252 code page that has been reencoded into UTF-8 without first being decoded

This string from your Excel file

```
Unverifiable License Documentation – NB Only
```

contains an EN DASH, which is represented as `"\x96"` in Windows-1252. If this is again encoded into UTF-8 the result is the two bytes `"\xC2\x96"`. Interpreting this using Windows-1252 results in the two characters LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX followed by EN DASH, which is what you're seeing

As far as I can tell, the only change necessary is to open your file with Windows-1252 decoding, like this

```perl
open my $fh, '<:encoding(Windows-1252)', $excel_file or die $!
```

---

#### Update

Your revised question shows your Perl code, but has removed the essential information from the Excel data that you show. This string

```
Unverifiable License Documentation  NB Only
```

now has just two spaces between `Documentation` and `NB` and omits the `"0x96"` n-dash

***Note*** *— I've since restored the original data and tidied your code.*

Your various attempts at opening the input file are here

```
$sts=open (INP, "< ${if}"       );
#$sts=open (INP, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', ${if}       );
#$sts=open (INP, '<:encoding(ISO-8859-1)', ${if}       );
```

and you came very close with `ISO-8859-1`, but Microsft, in their wisdom, have reused the gaps in ISO-8859-1 encoding between 0x7F and 0x9F to represent printable characters in Windows-1252. The n-dash character at 0x96 is inside this range, so decoding your input as ISO-8859-1 won't render it correctly

As far as I can see, you just need to write

```
$sts = open (INP, '<:encoding(Windows-1252)', ${if} );
```

and your input data will be read correctly

You should also specify the encoding of your output file to avoid `Wide character in print` warnings and malformed data. I can't tell whether you want to duplicate the encoding of your Excel file, use UTF-8, or something else entirely, but you should change this

```
$sts = open( OUT, ">$od/$WkS->{Name}.txt" );
```

to either

```
$sts = open OUT, '>:encoding(Windows-1252)', "$od/$WkS->{Name}.txt";
```

or
    $sts = open OUT, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', "$od/$WkS->{Name}.txt";

as appropriate

Note also that it is best practice to use the three-parameter form of `open` all the time, and it is best to use lexical file names instead of the global ones that you have. But this isn't a code review, so I've disregarded those points

I hope this underlines to you that it is *vital* to establish the encoding of your input data and decode it correctly. Guessing really isn't an option

---

#### Update

My apologies. I overlooked that the initial `open` is ignore by the `Spreadsheet::XLSX` module, which is passed a filename, rather than a file handle

This module is awkward in that it completely hides all character decoding, and relies on [`Text::Iconv`][Text::Iconv] to do the little conversion that it supports: something that is much better supported by Perl's own [`Encode`][Encode] module

The change I suggested to your `open` call is wrong, because it seems that a .xlsx file is a zipped file. However you never read from `INP` so it will make no difference. You should also `close INP` immediately after you have opened it as it is a wasted resource

Short of using a different module, the best thing I can suggest is that you hack the data returned by `Spreadsheet::XLSX->new`

This block will correct the erroneous re-encoding. I have added it right before your `foreach $iR` ( ... )` loop

You will need to add

```
use Encode qw/ decode :fallbacks /;
```

to the top of your code

Please let me know how you get on. Now I *really* must go!

```
{
    my $columns = $WkS->{Cells};

    for my $row ( @$columns ) {

        next unless $row;

        for my $cell ( @$row) {

            next unless $cell and $cell->type eq 'Text';

            for ( $cell->{_Value} ) {

                $_ = decode('UTF-8', $_, FB_CROAK);
                $_ = decode('Windows-1252', $_, FB_CROAK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i put the below command i am getting the below O/P

$sts = open OUT, '>:encoding(Windows-1252)', "$od/$WkS->{Name}.txt";

o/P:  Unverifiable Drivers License Documentation Â\x{0096} NB Only


For $sts = open OUT, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', "$od/$WkS->{Name}.txt"; i am getting the below

O/P: Unverifiable Drivers License Documentation Ã‚Â– NB Only


My Expected O/P :Unverifiable License Documentation  NB Only 

(Same as the Excel file value)

Can you please help on this.

Comment: What do you have for the line `$sts = open (INP, ...`?

Comment: The command suggested by you:$sts = open (INP, '<:encoding(Windows-1252)', ${if} );

Comment: @HariHaran: I can't see immediately, and I have to be out soon. Can you post the .xlsx file online so we can see the real thing?

Comment: Placed the Excel file in link:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2rtUdr0h6XJS0lFYmhGWGJteVE , In the Excel file i have highlighted the value which i am changing, but it is giving me the output with Â value.

Comment: Do i need to add the in my coding  {
    my $columns = $WkS->{Cells};

    for my $row ( @$columns ) {

        next unless $row;

        for my $cell ( @$row) {

            next unless $cell and $cell->type eq 'Text';

            for ( $cell->{_Value} ) {

                $_ = decode('UTF-8', $_, FB_CROAK);
                $_ = decode('Windows-1252', $_, FB_CROAK);
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Hi Borodin, I have added the "use Encode qw/ decode :fallbacks /;" even that i am getting the Â in that value, Can you please help on this.

Comment: @HariHaran: You need to add the `use` statement at the top with all the other `use` statements, and insert the block I have written right before the `foreach $iR` loop

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It worked fine now, Thank You very much.